# Is there are more pythonic way to write a while loop that only updates a variable?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this while loop, and I was wondering if their is a more pythonic way to write it:

```
k = 1
while np.sum(s[0:k]) / s_sum < retained_variance:
    k += 1
```

`s` is a numpy vector. Thanks!

Comment: are you sure the exit condition will be always reached at some point?

Comment: Rather than summing every value from 0 to `k` in every iteration, you should keep a running total and add the next value to it. You are turning a linear complexity problem into a quadratic one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient solution, but fast if most of the array needs to be searched:

```
import numpy as np

ss = np.cumsum(s)  # array with cumulative sum
k = ss.searchsorted(retained_variance*s_sum) # exploit that ss is monotonically increasing
```

EDIT: Simon pointed out that

```
k = np.cumsum(s).searchsorted(retained_variance*s_sum) + 1
```

is the value which corresponds to the question.

Comment: +1: I think this should be `ss.searchsorted(retained_variance*s_sum)+1` to match the model answer. This is better than my answer and I'd say it is the best of those offered so far.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say it's pretty pythonic: explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 2):

The last line of the following code will find the value of `k` in one line:

```
import numpy as np
import math

s = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
s_sum = 1
retained_variance = 4.3

k = 1
while np.sum(s[0:k]) / s_sum < retained_variance:
    k += 1

print (k)

print (np.ceil(np.interp(retained_variance,s.cumsum()/s_sum,range(1,len(s)+1))))
```

Answer (score 2):

this is more like Haskell than python:

```
>>> from itertools import count, dropwhile
>>> pred = lambda k: np.sum(s[:k]) / s_sum < retained_variance
>>> head = next  # just to look more like haskell
>>> head(dropwhile(pred, count()))
```

---

*edit*: this will be more efficient:

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile, accumulate
>>> pred = lambda x: x[1] / s_sum < retained_variance
>>> head = next
>>> head(dropwhile(pred, enumerate(accumulate(s), start=1)))[0]
```

Comment: `head = next` - why not use `next` without that alias?